# In Cassandra, are partition tombstones inherently less expensive compared to row/cell tombstones during compaction?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Let's say my table is modelled such that I only delete entire partitions instead of just some rows in them. That is to say, Cassandra will never create row tombstones but only partition tombstones.

Now, as I understand, the compaction process in Cassandra brings the partition entries in each of the SSTables into memory because it has to merge all the entries for a given partition across multiple SSTables. I would imagine this process to be costlier for partitions that have a lot of deleted rows (row tombstones) because the process has to go through all the rows across each SSTable for that partition and see which ones are marked to be deleted and merge the rows into a single SSTable. This, as opposed to processing the partition tombstones, in my case, which implies the entire partition is to be deleted.

Am I correct in assuming that the compaction process "doesn't have to worry much" about processing a tombstoned partition? As I understand, while merging the SSTables, if it comes across a partition that has been marked as a tombstone, it will simply move on to the next partition and this happens for all the SSTables that partition is present in. Eventually, the compaction ends with the deletion of all these old SSTables.

Is my understanding correct? Will deleting entire partitions prove less expensive compared to deleting (a large number of) rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your understanding that partition tombstone is better than row tombstone for compaction process. Also it helps in read flow. Reading is fast when you have partition tombstones instead of row tombstones. You can refer the [the lastpickle blog](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html) and comments in the blog.